# SQLite SELECT that returns ids and positions

Tags: sql, sqlite

Using a SQLite SELECT statement, I'd like to be able to get the position of each results.

Is that even possible?

**Table:**

```
fk_id   idx
0       0
0       1
0       2
1       0
1       1
1       3
1       4
2       0
```

Having [fk_id, idx] being unique.

**Query:**

```
SELECT `idx`, <??> from `mytable` WHERE `fk_id`=1
```

**Results:**

```
idx   <??>
0     0
1     1
3     2
4     3
```

The **`<??>`** being the "order"/"position"/"index" information I seek.

Comment: You want to do ranking. When you want to do ranking you have to make a decision about ties. Are ties possible? There is a difference between ranking and dense_ranking, ties are the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have analytic support - the closest you can get is to use a subselect:

```
SELECT mt.idx,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) - 1
          FROM mytable t
         WHERE t.fk_id = mt.fk_id
           AND t.idx <= mt.idx) AS position
  FROM mytable mt
 WHERE mt.fk_id = 1
```

The caveat here is that if you have duplicate `idx` values, they all get the same position value.  The only way with this method to get distinct values, is to add criteria that for logic to distinguish which of the duplicates comes first.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get the info from the hidden [`ROWID` column](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html), though that's probably going to be discontinuous (if that matters).